# Can the phrase "embark on" be used in the following sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Does it make sense to use the expression 'embark on' in the following sentence: "Jack embarks on a serious journey to save his brother, carrying him on his back through the dense forest."

Comment: Usually *embarks* is used at the beginning of a journey where only the goal is known and not what happened during.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The definition of "embark" is to start or to begin. You wouldn't use the expression "start on" or "begin on" in this case, but the use of "on" after "embark" is conventional for the verb in question.

Comment: “He has started on his journey” seems completely unremarkable to me.  I’m not sure I understand your point here.